# How to list openstack user groups of a different domain?

Tags: python, openstack

I am connecting with an admin account on the Default domain and I am attempting to list all of the user groups of a non-Default domain, but I cannot figure out how to do this and there is no list_groups() equivalent that I can find in the OpenStack API documentation.

This code sample only returns the groups that the 'admin' user belongs to, not a list of ALL the user groups in the cloud.

```
conn = openstack.connect(cloudname)
pprint(conn.identity.groups())
```

I am looking to accomplish something similar in python code to what the cli command accomplishes:

```
openstack group list --domain nonDefault
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only test this with users against my local OpenStack installation, but it looks as if you can provide a `domain_id` attribute. E.g:

```
>>> len(list(conn.identity.users(domain_id='default')))
300
>>> len(list(conn.identity.users(domain_id='13b2c494c91842a5a698ce51aace2c94')))
517
```

Notet that this requires the domain id, not the domain name. You can ask `conn.identity.domains()` for a list of domains if you want to map names to ids.

Comment: Does users(conn.identity.find_domain('mydomain')) return all group information? It also seems inefficient to loop through all users just to get a list of all the user groups.

Comment: The `users` endpoint does not provide group information (as I mentioned in the answer, I was only using `users` because we don't have any local groups defined so I can't test anything using the `groups` endpoint). If this answer provided you with what  you were looking for, please check the checkbox to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using larsks's help, found the answer in:

```py
pprint(list(conn.identity.groups(domain_id=conn.identity.find_domain('mydomain')['id'])))
```

The `domain_id=` parameter is undocumented where the parameters accepted are just `**query` without further explaination at: https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/proxies/identity_v3.html#domain-operations

Without the `list()` it would print only information about an generator/iterator and not the items themselves.